# Why no output from qx(ssh ...)?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, ssh, zfs

If I in Bash do

```
a=$(ssh 10.10.10.46 ifconfig)
```

then I see the output in `$a`, but if I in Perl do

```
my @a = qx(ssh 10.10.10.46 ifconfig);
print Dumper @a;
```

then I don't get the output. I have ssh keys, so no login required.

For now would I just like to get simple output, but later I want to pipe from the remote host to the local host all in bash. Will be used for ZFS replication.

**Question**

Why don't I see the output in Perl?

Comment: Do you get any output at all?

Comment: Are you running the programs as the same user?

Comment: I can't seem to recreate this issue on my machine, is this the code in its entirety? You could try examining STDERR as well: `my @a = qx(ssh 10.10.10.46 ifconfig 2>&1)`

Comment: What error are you getting? (What's `$?`? If `$?` is -1, what's `$!`? What was printed to STDERR?)

Comment: Hoping this won't apply, but just checking... You do have `use Data::Dumper` set at the top of the perl script?

Comment: First, confirm that the ssh session is successful by checking the server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the last `print`. Thanks for the debug tips. Very useful!

```
sub rrr {
   my $a = qx(ssh 10.10.10.46 ifconfig);
   return $a;
}

print rrr();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open(F,'ssh 10.10.10.46 ifconfig |');
my @a=<F>;
close(F);
print Dumper(@a);
```

Comment: Why does this answer the question? The question is *Why don't I see the output in Perl?*. So, posting code without a description is not ok.